# How to generate Scala setters and getters with IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

Give the simple class

```
class MyClass {
  private var myVar: String = _
}
```

How can I generate the setters and getters for `myVar`?

The `Code | Generate` menu shows:

- Override Methods...
- Implement Methods...
- Delegate Methods...
- Copyright
- equals() and hashCode()
- toString()
- Companion object

`IntelliJ` version: `14.1.5`
OS: `OS X 10.10.5`

Comment: I guess IntelliJ doesn't offer such a thing because getters and setters are really not idiomatic to scala. Scala uses mostly immutable classes with public fields (`val`s), analogous to having `public final` fields in a Java class.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

@Zoltán is right - getters and setters are not common in Scala because:

1. Scala encourages immutability
2. Scala already generates them for you when make a field  - they just aren't named according to the Java beans convention (You can encourage Scala to *not* generate these methods by being really restrictive in who can see and modify the field - think `final private[this] val`).
3. Because of #2, it is possible to go from `var someField` to `private var _someField`, `def someField = this._someField` and `def someField_=(value: String) = { this._someField = value }` and not have consumers update their code.  In other words, the change is source compatible  (though I believe it is not *binary* compatible).

If you need Java bean style getters and setters simply annotate the field with [`@BeanProperty`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.beans.BeanProperty) and *scalac* will generate the getter and setter for you:

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

class MyClass {
  @BeanProperty
  var myVar: String = _
}
```

Note that in order to get the `is` getters and setters for a boolean property you need to use `BooleanBeanProperty` instead.

Comment: This won't work because bean property should not be private.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the Scala [Bean Property](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.beans.BeanProperty)

```
import scala.beans.BeanProperty

class MyClass {
  @BeanProperty var myVar: String = _
}
```

- @BeanProperty - Generates getters and setters for a property. (Or
  just a getter if the bean is a val)